# Add a custom button to ABUnknownPersonViewController

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am using a ABUnknownPersonViewController for displaying contact information within UINavigatonController and I want a button at the bottom which will push another viewController with additional information on that user.  I have been able to add a button to the bottom and I can scroll down and view it, but it does not stay on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same thing, but can you please show me how did you add a button at the bottom?

What I did is add a button at the top, inside the navigation bar, although it does have a few visual problems, this is how i did it.

```
//I created a UIToolBar 
UIToolBar *myToolBar = [[UIToolBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
//then set the style to match my navBar
[myToolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
//and finally created the button.
NSMutableArray *buttons = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1]autorelease];
UIBarButtonItem *details = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init]autorelease];
[details setTitle: @"details"];
```

//after that placed it on top of the UPVC
unknownPersonViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myToolBar];

I hope this helps you in some way...

Comment: in my load view of my sub ABUnknownPersonViewController, I create a button, then I get the subviews.  I grab the first subview and cast it as a scroll view, then I go ahead and add it, and attempt to adjust the content size.
I don't think it is the best way to do it, but it does get a button down there

Comment: @pjloco in this code you're adding a UIToolBar as the rightBarButtonItem. You should add the UIBarButtonItem `details` directly as the rightBarButtonItem. There should be no need for the UIToolBar.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setTitle:@"Horray Button!!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 500.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    //[self.view addSubview:button];

    NSArray *subviews = [self.view subviews];
    NSLog(@"subviews: %d", [subviews count]);

    UIScrollView *v = [subviews objectAtIndex:0];

    [v addSubview:button];
    CGSize cgSize = [v contentSize];
    cgSize.height = 500.0 + 40.0;
    [v setContentSize:cgSize];
}
```

The code I am using to add the button down at the bottom, but it does not stay in view once scrolled to.